# Calling a function in a rust format string

Tags: rust

I'm working through the big crab book and there's an example function on dangling pointers:

```rust
fn no_dangle() -> String {
  let s = String::from("hello");
  s
}

let meow = no_dangle();

println!("{meow}");
```

This prints

```
hello
```

As expected.  Great.

However, it seems I can't call the `no_dangle()` function /without/ storing it to a temporary variable, directly inside the format.

```rust
println!("{no_dangle()}"); // kind of weird I can't call this.
```

Produces

```
println!("{no_dangle()}"); // kind of weird I can't call this.
                     expected `}` in format string
println!("{no_dangle()}"); // kind of weird I can't call this.
          ^ because of this opening brace
invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'('`
```

I am giving it both { and } which it seems to be asking for.

### Update

I followed the link on the question this was closed and linked to, but I don't understand the answer given---it had something to do with slice syntax, not calling functions.  I'm not asking about inconsistency, just how to call a function.

What is the correct syntax to call the function inside the format without using a temporary variable?

Comment: Regarding the update: the answers in the linked post explain the `"{...}"` syntax only works with *names*, not *expressions*. You cannot use arbitrary expressions. So to print the result of a function call, you need to store it in a local variable so it can be *named* in the format specifier.

Comment: Or of course, use the traditional syntax: `println!("{}", no_dangle())`